# How to add CRUD to Blazor Web Assembly with gRPC?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, grpc, blazor-webassembly

I'm following [this example](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/15/How-to-use-gRPC-Web-with-Blazor-WebAssembly-on-App-Service.html) about how to add gRPC to a hosted Blazor Web Assembly project.

I want to add CRUD using EF Core, and the simple problem I'm having is the example says to put my controller logic into the new Service.cs file in the Shared project -- but my dbContext file is in the Server project so it's not letting my inject my context into this Service.cs file. It doesn't seem right (good practice) to put my dbContext in the Shared folder?

```
namespace CertPortal.Shared
{
    public class CertificatesService : Certificates.CertificatesBase
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<CertPortalContext> _contextFactory;

        public CertificatesService(IDbContextFactory<CertPortalContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;

        }


        public async Task<Certificate> AddCertAsync(Certificate certVM)
        {
            try
            {
                using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
                await context.AddAsync(certVM);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return certVM;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the red squigglies on the 'CertPortalContext' in the IDbContextFactory<**CertPortalContext**>  parts.

Can someone tell me how I should proceed here?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not move your `CertPortalContext` class to the shared project?  Why is it bad practice?

Comment: Idk, that's just not what we do at work lol. I thought that was the place for ViewModels and such

Comment: You've got to put it somewhere where your Shared project can see it?  Personally my Blazor `Server` web projects contain almost no code, almost everything lives in the *Shared* project library.

Comment: Alright, I'll do it then! Thank you.